# Using API to create a Google Calendar event and conference accessible without Asking to join

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am able to create a google calendar with conference using the following code:

```
Event event = new Event()
.setSummary(calevent.getTitle())
.setDescription(calevent.getDescription());

ConferenceSolutionKey conferenceSolutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey().setType("hangoutsMeet");
CreateConferenceRequest createRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest().setRequestId("xxsdswwadx")
.setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSolutionKey);
ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData().setCreateRequest(createRequest);
event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);

DateTime startDateTime = convertDate(calevent.getStartDateTime());
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
.setDateTime(startDateTime)
.setTimeZone("Europe/London");
event.setStart(start);

DateTime endDateTime = convertDate(calevent.getEndDateTime());
EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
.setDateTime(endDateTime)
.setTimeZone("Europe/London");
event.setEnd(end);
```

But this does not allow invitees to join without waiting for moderator to accept them. On google calendar, there's a settings for conferences called 'Quick Access' that when turned off, allows anyone to join without having to be approved.

Can this be set when creating the conference?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to handle these settings via API. In any case, are attendees from your own domain? If that's the case, I think you should be able to turn off `Host management`, so that attendees are not required to request to join by default https://support.google.com/a/answer/7304109#safety

Comment: @lamblichus No attendees are not from my own domain and hosts are also NOT from our domain. We're trying to create a conference room to connect a customer with a vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

I don't think you can manage these settings via Calendar API. None of its resources include any field related to this.

#### Feature request:

I couldn't find any related feature request in Issue Tracker.

Therefore, if you're interested in this, I'd suggest you to request this feature using the corresponding [Issue Tracker template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906&pli=1).

Comment: Yes we ended up using Jitsi instead.